# SQL Server : maximum row size warning

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar

I have table with over 100 columns what are `varchar(200)`. We are changing all the columns to `nvarchar` but when running the alter script we are getting a warning message like this:

> Warning: The table "TABLE_NAME" has been created, but its maximum row
>   size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes. INSERT or UPDATE to
>   this table will fail if the resulting row exceeds the size limit.

Should I be alarmed by this or can I just ignore it?

Comment: I'd be concerned having a table that large to begin with, whatever happened to make that a requirement? can you revisit some data types and reduce the length?

Comment: Might be a good time to look at normalizing these 100 columns into something more manageable.

Comment: Ignore it? Really? Your inserts and/or updates could now start failing and you want to ignore it?

Comment: @RandyMinder, i see your point but what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actual even without moving to nvarchar - 200 bytes for each of 100 columns is 20000 bytes per row. Max row size in SQL Server is 8060 as given in warning text. It is only a warning because columns are **var**char which means they occupy as much space as they really need to store current data starting from zero. But if total length of all column exceeds max bound for any row - it will fail - server won't be able to store that row. That's what this warning is about.

Comment: All the fields will never be filled on any of the rows inserted to that table (maximum maybe 30). But i get what you are saying. Should remove unneeded ones...